# Set apache logs to write as www-data

Tags: linux, logging, chown

Can someone please explain how to chown the apache logs to user:www-data and set the apache server to write them as user:www-data ?  They are currently writing as root:adm

This is on a Ubuntu 10.10

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a million,

Comment: This is because when Apache starts it is running as root, it then opens the files, after which it drops it's privileges. Why not just add `user` to the `adm` group?

Comment: I just found `adm` group and fix an issue similar to this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120584/reading-apache-error-logs-from-php. Now I am looking if this is secure ?